# Is there a difference between the keras' implementation of the categorical cross entropy and the actual one?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Those two lines produce different results while training

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(answers_matrix, predictions_matrix))
```

and

```
loss = -tf.reduce_mean(answers_matrix * tf.log(predictions_matrix))
```

I want to visualize the loss during the training so I want to print the mean of losses over the entire batch and over the sequence length. without taking the mean, the resulting loss would be of shape (batch_size, sequence_length)

The second line gives me WAY better results while training/optimizing the neural network.
I use keras with tensorflow backend

Comment: Are your outputs from sigmoid or softmax?

Comment: the last layer in my keras model has softmax activations

Comment: Why are you taking the mean over the categorical loss? It should not be required at all.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro because I want to visualize the loss during the training so I want the mean of losses over the entire batch and over the sequence length. without taking the mean, the resulting loss would be of shape (batch_size, sequence_length)

Comment: Then it seems that there are lots of details that you are leaving out of the question, add them all.